# Why is the cordova-local-notification-plugin not working (Phonegap, Android)?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins

I built a Phonegap App with [this plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git), and it seems, as it is used in the app: 
[image]

**The config.xml** :

`<plugin spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git#b8f358e" />`

But when I try to send local notifications it looks like the plugin doesn't work. I tried this:

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () 
    {
        alert(1);


        cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
           id:      1,
           title:   'Some Timer',
           message: 'Some Message'
        });

        alert(2);

    }, false);
```

But only the first `alert` is working, that's why I think that the plugin isn't working right. So how can I build an App to send local notifications?

Thank you very much :-)

---

**cordova -v**
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

**cordova plugin ls**
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"

But as shown above, I added the local.notification plugin in the config.xml, and the Adobe Phonegap Build webpage, says that the plugin is used.

**cordova platform ls**
Installed platforms:
  android 8.0.0
  browser 4.1.0
Available platforms:
  electron ^1.0.0
  ios ^5.0.0
  osx ^5.0.0
  windows ^7.0.0

---

**PS:** I posted a similar question two days ago, but I edited it to specify my question.

Comment: can you please give the versions you are working on? just show result for `cordova -v`, `cordova plugin ls`, `cordova platform ls`

Comment: Of course, I edited the post to share the information. Thank you

Comment: How did you conclude that issue is from local notification plugin?

Comment: It's the only plugin that is not pre-installed, and without the plugin I could build the app

Comment: I can build the app now, but the notifications still don't work

Comment: Did you check logcat for errors?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You need to load app onto Android Studio, and then load to phone using Android Studio. I can provide more info in the answer if its really required.

Comment: Okay, I opened the Android emulator and loaded the app into it. Logcat only showed two errors when the phone was booting, there were no errors when opening or using the app. But the notification didn't work here too. I don't know if it's helpful but here you could see my code: http://www.niklas-lochmann.de/notificationApp.zip Thank you anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the file. I was able to run successfully your app and the notifications works each time. However, you need to edit the code as below

**For notifications without ID param**

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    title: 'My first notification',
    text: 'Thats pretty easy...',
    foreground: true
});
```

**For notifications with ID param, ID should be unique**

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule([
    { id: 1, title: 'My Second notification' },
    { id: 2, title: 'My Third notification' }
]);
```

**Index.js**

```
var app = {
  // Application Constructor
  initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
  },
  onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
  },
  receivedEvent: function(id) {    
    oneNotification();
    multipleNotification();
  }
};

app.initialize();

function oneNotification() {
  cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    title: 'My first notification',
    text: 'Thats pretty easy...',
    foreground: true
  });
}

function multipleNotification() {
  cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule([{
      id: 1,
      title: 'My Second notification'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'My Third notification'
    }
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's really impressive! But it doesn't work for me yet. Did you build the app by using the Adobe website or the command line? I work with the website. And thank you for your efforts!

Comment: @WilliWespe have edited the post to include the code I am using.

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I thank you very very much! Your the best! I hope it didn't bother you too much. Thank you :-)

Comment: not an issue, happy to help. Good luck with rest of your code ..!!

Comment: Had a similar problem, setting foreground: true seems to have fixed it...